# How can I make a slideshow to change its picture by dragging the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I have a slideshow I found on the internet and I wanted to use it for a project. The slideshow was supposed to be just the screen with scrolling disabled (you use the scroll wheel to change its slides).

Here's a link to a demo: https://aurelia-test.000webhostapp.com/
Here's a link to the slider https://www.toptal.com/css/full-page-slider-css-and-javascript

The slider I mentioned is on top on every page. It uses divs and background image for each slide. I don't know what code to include exactly so here is its JS.

If any other code is needed I will edit the post and add it.

So, can I make it work when I drag the mouse to the left to change to the next slide and backwards and disable the scroll?

```js
/**
 *  Utility functions
 */
function utils() {
  /**
   * Returns max height value for a nodelist
   * @param {NodeList} nodeList The node list to calculate max height of
   */
  const calcMaxHeight = function(items) {
    let maxHeight = 0;

    items.forEach(item => {
      const h = item.clientHeight;
      maxHeight = h > maxHeight ? h : maxHeight;
    });
    return maxHeight;
  }

  /**
   * Removes Classes from NodeList
   * @param {NodeList} nodeList The node list to remove classes from
   * @param {Array} cssClasses Array of CSS classes to be removed
   */
  function removeClasses(nodeList, cssClasses) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
      nodeList[i].classList.remove(...cssClasses);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds Classes from NodeList
   * @param {NodeList} nodeList The node list to add classes to
   * @param {Array} cssClasses Array of CSS classes to be added
   */
  function addClasses(nodeList, cssClasses) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
      nodeList[i].classList.add(...cssClasses);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Behaves the same as setInterval except uses requestAnimationFrame() where possible for better performance
   * @param {function} fn The callback function
   * @param {int} delay The delay in milliseconds
   */
  const requestInterval = function(fn, delay) {
    const requestAnimFrame = (function() {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || function(callback, element) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();

    let start = new Date().getTime(),
      handle = {};

    function loop() {
      const current = new Date().getTime(),
        delta = current - start;

      if (delta >= delay) {
        fn.call();
        start = new Date().getTime();
      }

      handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }

    handle.value = requestAnimFrame(loop);
    return handle;
  };

  /**
   * Behaves the same as clearInterval except uses cancelRequestAnimationFrame() where possible for better performance
   * @param {int|object} handle The callback function
   */
  const clearRequestInterval = function(handle) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame ? window.cancelAnimationFrame(handle.value) :
      clearInterval(handle);
  };

  return {
    calcMaxHeight,
    removeClasses,
    addClasses,
    requestInterval,
    clearRequestInterval
  }
}


/**
 *  Main Slider function
 */
function heroSlider() {
  const slider = {
    hero: document.querySelector('#hero-slider'),
    main: document.querySelector('#slides-main'),
    aux: document.querySelector('#slides-aux'),
    current: document.querySelector('#slider-nav .current'),
    handle: null,
    idle: true,
    activeIndex: -1,
    interval: 3500
  };

  const setHeight = function(holder, items) {
    const h = utils().calcMaxHeight(items);
    holder.style.height = `${h}px`;
  }

  const leadingZero = function() {
    return arguments[1] < 10 ? '0' + arguments[1] : arguments[1];
  }

  const setCurrent = function() {
    slider.current.innerText = leadingZero `${slider.activeIndex + 1}`;
  }

  const changeSlide = function(direction) {
    slider.idle = false;
    slider.hero.classList.remove('prev', 'next');
    if (direction == 'next') {
      slider.activeIndex = (slider.activeIndex + 1) % slider.total;
      slider.hero.classList.add('next');
    } else {
      slider.activeIndex = (slider.activeIndex - 1 + slider.total) % slider.total;
      slider.hero.classList.add('prev');
    }

    //reset classes
    utils().removeClasses(slider.items, ['prev', 'active']);

    //set prev
    const prevItems = [...slider.items]
      .filter(item => {
        let prevIndex;
        if (slider.hero.classList.contains('prev')) {
          prevIndex = slider.activeIndex == slider.total - 1 ? 0 : slider.activeIndex + 1;
        } else {
          prevIndex = slider.activeIndex == 0 ? slider.total - 1 : slider.activeIndex - 1;
        }

        return item.dataset.index == prevIndex;
      });

    //set active
    const activeItems = [...slider.items]
      .filter(item => {
        return item.dataset.index == slider.activeIndex;
      });

    utils().addClasses(prevItems, ['prev']);
    utils().addClasses(activeItems, ['active']);
    setCurrent();

    const activeImageItem = slider.main.querySelector('.active');
    activeImageItem.addEventListener('transitionend', waitForIdle, {
      once: true
    });
  }

  const stopAutoplay = function() {
    slider.autoplay = false;
    utils().clearRequestInterval(slider.handle);
  }

  const waitForIdle = function() {
    !slider.autoplay && autoplay(false); //restart
    slider.idle = true;
  }

  const wheelControl = function() {
    slider.hero.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
      if (slider.idle) {
        const direction = e.deltaY > 0 ? 'next' : 'prev';
      }
    });
  }

  const autoplay = function(initial) {
    slider.autoplay = true;
    slider.items = slider.hero.querySelectorAll('[data-index]');
    slider.total = slider.items.length / 2;

    const loop = () => changeSlide('next');

    initial && requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    slider.handle = utils().requestInterval(loop, slider.interval);
  }

  const loaded = function() {
    slider.hero.classList.add('loaded');
  }

  const touchControl = function() {
    const touchStart = function(e) {
      slider.ts = parseInt(e.changedTouches[0].clientX);
      window.scrollTop = 0;
    }

    const touchMove = function(e) {
      slider.tm = parseInt(e.changedTouches[0].clientX);
      const delta = slider.tm - slider.ts;
      window.scrollTop = 0;

      if (slider.idle) {
        const direction = delta < 0 ? 'next' : 'prev';
        stopAutoplay();
        changeSlide(direction);
      }
    }

    slider.hero.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
    slider.hero.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
  }

  const start = function() {
    autoplay(true);
    wheelControl();
    window.innerWidth <= 1024 && touchControl();
    slider.aux.addEventListener('transitionend', loaded, {
      once: true
    });
  }

  const loadingAnimation = function() {
    slider.hero.classList.add('ready');
    slider.current.addEventListener('transitionend', start, {
      once: true
    });
  }

  const init = function() {
    setHeight(slider.aux, slider.aux.querySelectorAll('.slide-title'));
    loadingAnimation();
  }

  const resize = function() {
    setHeight(slider.aux, slider.aux.querySelectorAll('.slide-title'));
  }

  return {
    init,
    resize
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', heroSlider().init);
window.addEventListener("resize", heroSlider().resize);
```

```html
<div id="hero-slider">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slides-main" class="slides">
      <div class="slide" data-index="0">
        <div class="abs-mask">
          <div class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(image)"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" data-index="1">
        <div class="abs-mask">
          <div class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(image)"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slides-aux" class="slides mask">
      <h2 class="slide-title slide" data-index="0">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </h2>
     <nav id="slider-nav">
        <span class="current">01</span>
        <span class="sep"></span>
        <span class="total">31</span>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It fails since it is missing `'#slider-nav .current'`

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry, I am really new to stack overflow and web development at all